# Prove $\nabla_X (w(Y)) = (\nabla_X w)(Y) + w(\nabla_X Y)$ directly

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $w$ is one form and $X,Y$ are vectors. For affine connection $\nabla_X$, From its definition

\begin{align}
(\nabla_X T)_p = \lim_{s\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{s} ( \tau_{s}^{-1} T_{\varphi(s)}-T_p) 
\end{align}
where $T$ is a tensor type of $(p,q)$ and $\tau$ is the parallel translation along curve $\gamma$

From this definition I want to prove

\begin{align}
\nabla_X (w(Y)) = (\nabla_X w)(Y) + w(\nabla_X Y)
\end{align}
this via definition.

My trials are 
\begin{align}
(\nabla_X (w(Y)))_p= \lim_{s\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{s} ( \tau_{s}^{-1} w(Y)_{\varphi(s)}-w(Y)_p)
\end{align}
But having trouble in expressing this into right hand sides..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be confused by the fact that you are denoting by the same symbol $\tau$ the parallel transport of any tensor along $\gamma$ while in reality you actually parallel transport tensors of different types differently.

Let's denote the parallel transport of tangent vectors along $\gamma$ from $\gamma(0)$ to $\gamma(s)$ by $\tau_s \colon T_{\gamma(0)} M \rightarrow T_{\gamma(s)} M$. Also denote the parallel transport of covectors along $\gamma$ by $\mu_s \colon T_{\gamma(0)}^{*} M \rightarrow T_{\gamma(s)}^{*} M$. The relation between $\mu_s$ and $\tau_s$ is given by

$$ \mu_s(\varphi) = \varphi \circ \tau_s^{-1} = \left( \tau_s^{-1} \right)^{*} \left( \varphi \right). $$

Hence, if $\gamma$ is a curve with $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0) = X_p$ then

$$ (\nabla_X w)(Y)|_{p} = \left( \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{\mu_s^{-1} \omega_{\gamma(s)} - \omega_{\gamma(0)}}{s} \right) \left( Y_p \right) = \left( \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{\tau_s^{*}(w_{\gamma(s)}) - \omega_{\gamma(0)}}{s} \right)(Y_p) \\
= \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{\omega_{\gamma(s)} \left( \tau_s(Y_p) \right) - \omega_{\gamma(0)}(Y_p)}{s}  \\
= \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{\omega_{\gamma(s)} (Y_{\gamma(s)}) - \omega_{\gamma(0)}(Y_{\gamma(0)}) + \omega_{\gamma(s)} \left( \tau_s(Y_p) \right) - \omega_{\gamma(s)}(Y_{\gamma(s)})}{s} \\
= \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{\omega_{\gamma(s)}(Y_{\gamma(s)}) - \omega_{\gamma(0)}(Y_{\gamma(0)})}{s} - \lim_{s \to 0} \left( \left( \omega_{\gamma(s)} \circ \tau_s \right) \left(  \frac{\tau_s^{-1} \left( Y_{\gamma(s)} \right) -  Y_{\gamma(0)}}{s} \right) \right) \\
\lim_{s \to 0} \frac{\omega_{\gamma(s)}(Y_{\gamma(s)}) - \omega_{\gamma(0)}(Y_{\gamma(0)})}{s} - \left( \lim_{s \to 0} \left( \omega_{\gamma(s)} \circ \tau_s \right) \right) \left( \lim_{s \to 0}  \frac{\tau_s^{-1} \left( Y_{\gamma(s)} \right) -  Y_{\gamma(0)}}{s} \right). $$

The first term tends by definition to $X(\omega(Y))|_{p}$ while the second tends to $\omega_{p}(\nabla_X Y|_{p})$ using the fact that $\omega_{\gamma(s)} \circ \tau_s \to \omega_{\gamma(0)} \circ \tau_0 = \omega_p$.